# InputStream which is faster read() or read(byte,offset,length)

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am writing an app for android which uses `InputStream` from `Socket`. I am trying to send a file from pc to android this way. The size of the file is almost 40kb and on android I am finding that it is able to read only 2kb of data at a time so I am reading it in chunks.

I have two methods for reading bytes

1)

```
while((d=inputStream.read())>=0)
{
    imgData[i]=(byte)d;
    i++;
    if(i>=40054)
    {
        // do the further processing here like saving it on disk.
        i=0;
    }
}
```

2)

```
while(inputStream.read(byte,0,2048)>=0)
{
    //merge this byte to buffer here... 
    i=i+2048;
    if(i>=40054)
    {
        // do the further processing here like saving it on disk.
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Form these 2 methods which will be faster in terms of performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second, potentially by a long way. Reading a block at a time is almost always preferable to reading a byte at a time, unless you *really* only want to read a single byte anyway.

However, your code is currently broken, in that you don't take account of the return value of `read` other than to check that *something* has been read. It may not have read 2048 bytes. You should use something like:

```
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
{
    // Use bytesRead here
}
```

With this code in place, you may well be able to read more than 2K at a time safely in *some* situations... it depends on the network, but at least the code will be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

@Op, You can also create a BufferedInputStream with a specified buffer size, and read chuncks from the buffered stream.